# Want to select data from two tables, where i need to count a column and join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two data tables like table name **block**

```
|ID | Name |
|1  | B1   |
|2  | B2   |
```

Then i have another table named as block_worker

```
|block_id | Name | No Of Worker|
|1        | sam|
|1        | dave|
|2        |  Rob |
```

Now i want to write a query which show me data from block table and count the number of worker in `block worker` table according to the `block id`.

The result would be something like this

```
|ID | Name | Worker
|1 | B1 |   2    |
|2 | B2 |   1    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select b.id, b.name, count(w.name) as Workers
from block b
left join block_worker w on w.block_id = b.id
group by b.id, b.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try Like this

    SELECT A.ID,A.Name,COUNT(B.block_id) AS Worker FROM block AS A JOIN block_worker AS B 
ON A.ID = B.block_id GROUP BY B.block_id
```